# Export BIOS Settings

Tags: bios, hardware

I'd like to be able to export the BIOS settings for systems with SuperMicro H8SCM-F motherboards.  I need to be able to process the results programmatically, so text output is ideal.  What sort of tool/utility exists to provide the settings export functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using IPMI?  You may be able to get many of the BIOS settings using IPMI while the box is running....spool it off, scp wherever you'd like, process it, etc. On linux you will need ipmitool.